# Difference between Log and Log10

Tags: expression-construction

I typed a function :

```
 f := Tan[(1/a)*Log[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])]] - y/x
```

I assigned values:

```
a = 6.045059888;
x = 8.36488;
y = 1.836539;
```

When I used

```
Evaluate[f]
```

it gave me a value of 0.15145

However, the correct value (verified on calculator and Excel), is supposed to be -0.064. Anyone know what is wrong with this?

Regards
Corse

Comment: Code is ok, `Log` has base `E`, not `10`. With `Log10` you will get what you need. P.s. `Evaluate` is redundant here.

Comment: how to evaluate the expression?

Comment: Use only `f`. p.s. If you want to create the function, maybe better use named arguments `f[a_,x_, y_]:=...` because your way works only if a x y were not defined earlier.

Comment: when i changed it to named arguments, `Evaluate[f]` just yields `f` . strange

Comment: Do `Remove[f]`, then redefine your function using the `f[a_, x_, y_]:=...` form, then apply your newly defined function `f[a,x,y]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the log with base $e$ instead of base 10.

```
Tan[1/a Log[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]] - y/x /. {a -> 6.045059888, 
  x -> 8.36488, y -> 1.836539}
0.15145


Tan[1/a Log[10, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]] - y/x /. {a -> 6.045059888, 
  x -> 8.36488, y -> 1.836539}
-0.0640291
```

Comment: or Log10 [Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]